# What Alternatives Exist for the Deprecated Google Earth API?

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

The Google Earth API was deprecated in Dec 2014 and will go offline in Dec 2015. As far as I know, Google hasn't announced an alternative.

What alternatives exist? Or does anyone have any insight into Google's plans or wishes to make informed speculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130910/google-earth-plugin-deprecated-which-alternatives) on another Stack Exchange site.  The consensus is that 
[Cesium](http://cesiumjs.org/) is the best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new service Melown API available at [www.melown.com](http://www.melown.com), they offer generous conditions. Here you can find some examples, what you cand do with Melown: [Melown Maps](https://www.melown.com/maps/)